# How to Animate the if body in knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, javascript-framework

I have one knockoutjs observable variable called "state" and i am using that variable to hide and show content in knockout with if condition like below:

```
<--if: state()=="login" -->
login content
<--/if-->

<--if: state()=="registration" -->
registration content
<--/if-->
```

whenever state variable changes it shows or hides the content. So my question is that i want to add animation of toggling behavior when it hides or shows for this. how would i be able to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/ujSvb/1/

for a more dynamic example

http://jsfiddle.net/ujSvb/2/

Comment: Nice work, but maybe an example of giving a man a fish vs. teaching a man to fish?

Comment: The "if" binding in knockout actually removes the elements from the DOM (probably using something similar to jQuery detach method).  But the examples in the fiddles just hide the elements, so they are not really doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you may have some error in your code there(may have just copied it over wrong) but it should be:

```
<-- ko if: state()=="login" -->
login content
<--/ko-->

<-- ko if: state()=="registration" -->
registration content
<--/ko-->
```

Second, if you can use jQuery along with binding on elements instead of using virtual elements such as:

```
<div data-bind="if: state()=="login">
```

You can utilize Knockout's [bindingHandlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). I have created an ifTransition binding which does what you want. Here's a fiddle with the bindingHandler and a sample of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rynan/vtPT8/

### Update

Okay, I updated my fiddle to utilize the virtual elements but you will still have to wrap your login and registration content within a div to get the transition affect you are looking for. Keeping with your comment, that div won't be rendered until the state has changed to whatever it needs to be to display those certain contents so it won't take much memory while it isn't in the correct state.

Comment: but the thing is that i am using this in phone memory replacing div is not solution because phones are having less memory and if statement makes sure that this body part hidden and not taking much memory.

Comment: @Vishal See my update to see if that is more along the lines you need.

Answer (score 0):

I further updated Anders' fiddle to add the state condition:

http://jsfiddle.net/ujSvb/3/

Answer (score 0):

Top voted answer isn't a solution since it doesn't unrender the elements.

Austins answer doesn't appear to work at all.

See my response in:
[Animation before 'with' binding update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558349/animation-before-with-binding-update/21734548#21734548)

for a clean workaround I've discovered, replacing 'if' and 'with' with roughly equivalent 'template' bindings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback you gave, but please add your statements as comments, and not as an actual answer. Thanks.

Comment: I would if this site wasn't so gamified that it doesn't allow a user to functionally use the website until they grown their epeen to a certain size.